# What happens when we set different processor affinity to process and its thread in linux?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, scheduling, smp

what happens when we set different processor affinity to process and its thread in linux.

I am trying to start a process affined to a core (say 1)  which have two threads one of which need to run on other core (say 0)

When i tried to set affinity to thread different to process the program got executed. but I want to know the hidden impacts of this approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Threads and processes are vastly the same thing. Whether you call `pthread_setaffinity...` or use the `sched_setaffinity` syscall, they both affect the *current thread's affinity mask*. This may be your "process" thread, or a thread you created.

However, note that a new thread created by `pthread_create` inherits a copy of its creator's CPU affinity mask [[1]](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html).

That means that setting the affinity and creating a thread is not the same as creating a thread and setting the affinity. In the first case, both threads will compete over the same processor (which is most probably not what you want) and in the second case they will be bound to different processors.

Also note that while binding threads to a dedicated processor (core) may have advantages in some situations, it may just as well be a very stupid thing to do. Playing with the affinity mask means you limit the scheduler in what it can do to make your program run. If the core you bound your thread to isn't available, your thread will not run, end of story.
This is a very similar reasoning/strategy as disabling swap to make the system "faster" (some users still do that!). By doing so they usually gain nothing, all they do is limit what the memory manager can do by removing one option of providing a free page once it runs out of unused physical RAM. Usually this means something more or less valuable from the buffer cache is purged when instead some private page that wasn't used in hours could have been swapped out.

Usually people use affinity because they have this idea that the scheduler will make threads bounce between processor cores all the time and this is bad. Processor migration indeed is not cheap, but the scheduler has a mechanism which makes sure it does not happen before a certain minimum amount of time (there is a `/proc` thingie for that too). After a longer amount of time, all advantages of staying at the old core (TLB, cache) are usually gone anyway, so running on a different core which is readily available is actually better than waiting for a particular core to maybe, eventually become available.

NUMA architectures may be a different topic, but I'd assume (though I don't know for sure) that the scheduler is smart enough not to silently migrate a thread to a different node. In general, however, I'd recommend not to play with affinity at all.

Comment: I strongly suspect that mnay such 'set affinity' posts are an attempt to band-aid over bad designs.

Comment: @Damon Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. In my case I am restricting the scheduler not to run on the core and i am running my thread on it. so I guess unavailability of core while scheduling wont come in to picture. and I am running my second thread in other core in which scheduler working. Is this works fine for my realtime program to run efficiently ?

Comment: Using [isolcpus](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/kernel_configuration/re46.html) bootarg we can control scheduler not to schedule any task on particular core. I am using this approach to get whole core for my purpose.

Comment: Ah OK, that will work (not 100% foolproof, since nothing prevents another process from setting affinity, but I guess it's as good as you can get, though obviously overall system performance may suffer -- which seems to be secondary to you as long as that one thread gets to run). Relying on booting the kernel in a particular mode or with particular parameters a bit of a harsh thing, but yeah, why not if you really need such a hard reserve.

Comment: In this case, if I have a thread1 affined to dedicate core and other thread2 affined to shared core in a process affined to dedicated core. Will this work fine? If yes is there any overhead on thread1 due to scheduling thread2 on shared core?

Comment: There should not be. In any case, thinking about other threads that might set affinity, since you already boot with isolated cores, you can as well use `SCHED_FIFO` @ 99, which really isn't any more intrusive than that. Then your process runs unpreempted until you block in an I/O request or until you call `sched_yield` or `sleep`.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable info :)

Answer (score 0):

Affinity is a common first line approach to limiting jitter in HPC. Typically LINUX processes and threads and such are constrained to a small but sufficient set of CPUs and the application is constrained to the remainder of the CPUs.

Affinity is very useful with device drivers. Consider for example an Infiniband adapter being used by an application. The adapter will perform best if the driver thread(s) are constrained to CPUs on the same (or closest if none) NUMA node as the adapter. LINUX doesn't know the application thread so can't even consider any affinity for performance.